# Why doesn't Yarn install all executables in .bin folder?

Tags: npm, ionic2, yarnpkg

I've just started using the Yarn package manager and I downloaded a starter Ionic 2 project.

In this project, we have a lot of help from scripts that compile, minify, lint and bundle our code. All of this is provided by [ionic-app-scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts), which has several dependencies which it uses to run commands.

The problem is when I use Yarn to install, the node_modules/.bin/ folder does not contain all the necessary executables, like `tslint`, which is a dependency of ionic-app-scripts, so it is not directly in my `package.json`.

The result is that when I use Yarn, ionic-app-scripts doesn't work because it  expects that the `.bin` folder contains a tslint executable!

What can I do? Are the ionic-app-scripts's definitions a problem?

[note]: npm install works, but Yarn is much faster!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/760), and there's a [pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/1210) with more information.

In short, if you want to fix this now, you'll have to explicitly include the packages from which you need binaries in your dependencies.

Comment: Still the case with v1.13.0 - `yarn install --force` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but a different solution.

The solution was from this ticket https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/992#issuecomment-318996260

> ... my workaround is going to file manager, right click on /node_modules main folder, selecting properties, and check-uncheck "read-only". You can do it also using attrib in command line. Then you retry installation and it works.